how do you performn division calculation on number of columns over a common column in pandas
I have this data frame:
Node       Band    5-May    12-May    19-May    26-May   2-June
Server1    10000   800      1000      12000     12500    500
Server2    30000   600      3000      12000     12500    500
Server3    17000   1500     12000     12500     500      1000

I need to calculate usage by dividing column values right of "Band" column by the values in "Band" column in pandas.
Resulting data frame should look like this:
df1

Node       Band    5-May    12-May    19-May    26-May   2-June
Server1    10000   0.08     0.10      1.2     1.25       0.05
Server2    30000   0.02     0.1       0.4     0.42       0.02
etc

then I have to count the them if they fall withing certain percentage per node. if any date, usage per node between 70% and 80%, the count for that node is one, however many times the usage is between those thresholds. In this example for Node "Server1", number of times it breached 100% is 2.
For example:
All summary:
Node    70%-80%  80%-90% 90%-100% 100%+
Server1  0          0       0         2
Server2  0          0       0         0

I can do this by explicitly dividing columns by Band column but the number of columns is not known, it could be many columns.
df['5-May_%']=df['5-May']/df['Band']


"but the number of columns is not known, it could be many columns." - Have you done a Pandas tutorial? Any good tutorial should cover how to select multiple columns. For example you can look at Selection by label in 10 Minutes to Pandas or the full Selection by label section in the User Guide.

This post asks two questions. It should be split up over multiple posts.

Another possible solution:
d = df.loc[:, '5-May':'2-June'].div(df['Band'], axis=0)
labs = ['70%-80%', '80%-90%', '90%-100%', '100%+']
bins = [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, np.inf]

pd.concat([ # concatenates the 2 first columns to the freq counts
    df.loc[:, 'Node':'Band'], # 2 first columns
    pd.concat([ # concatenates the series with the freqs per bin
        pd.cut(y.values, bins=bins, labels=labs)
        .describe()['counts'] # this is a series with the freq counts per bin
        for _, y in d.iterrows()], axis=1).T.iloc[:, :-1] # removes NA column
    .reset_index(drop=True) ], axis=1)

Output:
      Node   Band  70%-80%  80%-90%  90%-100%  100%+
0  Server1  10000        0        0         0      2
1  Server2  30000        0        0         0      0
2  Server3  17000        2        0         0      0


Column names cannot be hard coded, since it will be changing week to week. It needs to be anthing after Band

Just replace df.loc[:, '5-May':'2-June']  by df.iloc[:, 2:].

In case the index of column Band is uncertain, you can use df.iloc[:, (np.where(df.columns == 'Band')[0][0]+1):] instead df.iloc[:, 2:].

this almost worked but for the bin 100%+, eventhough the actual count is 1, it says 12

I do not quite well understand the reason why you are claiming my code does not work, as, given the example you provide in your original post, the results of my code are exactly what they should be.be. Could you please elaborate upon it?

my data frame is a lot bigger that what is provided. I also see some nan values in my data frame set. Would that be reason why I am not getting the accurate calculation?

Maybe, that is the reason. I would suggest that you post a small subset of your data where my code does not produce the result you need -- that would help me to figure out the reason and adapt my code accordingly.

I am still at this and making no progress. Do you think I need to start from row 1 on this line df.loc[:, 'Node':'Band']?

I suspect not. The line of code df.loc[:, 'Node':'Band'] only adds, to the resulting dataframe, the two first columns, but does not interfere at all in the calculations.

this works for some of the data frame and starts miscalculating it. It may have something to do with matching with "Node" after the calculations done. Is there any way to keep "Node" column through out the steps to make sure all the columns match with Node column?

Please, post a dataframe that exhibits the issue and the expected output, to make my code working also in those cases.

it's not possible to put the whole df, I tried to put a very small subset of Dat frame here. When I print out the dd, I get all of the raws calculated, it's acuurare. It's when I try to count the occorence towards the end of the counts, I get nan values for some of the nodes.

Unfortunately, without an example, it is not possible to find out the cause of the issue.

For the first output, select the columns, div and combine_first:
cols = df.columns.difference(['Node', 'Band'], sort=False)

out = df[cols].div(df['Band'], axis=0).combine_first(df)[list(df)]

Output:
      Node   Band     5-May    12-May    19-May    26-May    2-June
0  Server1  10000  0.080000  0.100000  1.200000  1.250000  0.050000
1  Server2  30000  0.020000  0.100000  0.400000  0.416667  0.016667
2  Server3  17000  0.088235  0.705882  0.735294  0.029412  0.058824

However, if your goal is to get the second output you don't really need this intermediate. Instead you can directly melt, cut and crosstab:
tmp = df.melt(['Node', 'Band'])

s = pd.cut(tmp['value'].div(tmp['Band']),
           bins=[0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, np.inf],
           labels=['70%-80%', '80%-90%', '90%-100%', '100%+']
          )

out = (pd.crosstab(tmp['Node'], s, dropna=False)
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )

If you want to limit the analysis to a set of columns, use value_vars in melt. For instance, to only consider the last four columns:
tmp = df.melt(['Node', 'Band'], value_vars=df.columns[-4:])

Output:
      Node  70%-80%  80%-90%  90%-100%  100%+
0  Server1        0        0         0      2
1  Server2        0        0         0      0
2  Server3        2        0         0      0


@mozday, thank you for your answer. What if if you wanted to pick the last 4 column from data frame regardless of how many columns do you have for the same calculation?

You can use df.iloc[:, -4]. For the full logic out depends what you want to do exactly. You can restrict the columns to melt with value_vars=list(df)[-4:].

when I do s.head(), I get nan values. When I execute out, I get this error: TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category.

@user1471980 please be explicit, edit your answer and provide a DataFrame constructor of the problematic input and the exact code that reproduces the issue. Also specify your pandas version.

pandas version: 1.0.5

@user1471980 this version is very old, any chance you can update to a more recent one? This works fine on pandas 2.2.2
